# Keras/HDF5 TypeError: PointSelection __getitem__ only works with bool arrays

Tags: python, keras, hdf5

When I try load training data from an HDF5 file using fit_generator and generator functions, I get a ValueError, which results from a PointSelectionError with HDF5:

```
Epoch 1/10
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 429, in data_generator_task
    generator_output = next(self._generator)
  File "osr.py", line 108, in generate_training_sequences
    X = training_save_file["X"][batch_idxs]
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (/tmp/pip-4rPeHA-build/h5py/_objects.c:2684)
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (/tmp/pip-4rPeHA-build/h5py/_objects.c:2642)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/dataset.py", line 462, in __getitem__
    selection = sel.select(self.shape, args, dsid=self.id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/selections.py", line 72, in select
    sel[arg]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/selections.py", line 210, in __getitem__
    raise TypeError("PointSelection __getitem__ only works with bool arrays")
TypeError: PointSelection __getitem__ only works with bool arrays

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "osr.py", line 359, in <module>
    osr.train_osr_model()
  File "osr.py", line 89, in train_osr_model
    nb_worker=1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1532, in fit_generator
    str(generator_output))
ValueError: output of generator should be a tuple (x, y, sample_weight) or (x, y). Found: None
```

I researched the error and it was mentioned that it could be due to duplicate indices, but that does not seem to be true in my case. Here are the row indices that were accessed:

```
[581 305  67 510 631 832 340 663 689 801 579 701 831 879 382 844  15 798
 342 329 118 657 503 129 602   2 528 157 341 299 731 539]
```

Here are the training and generation functions:

```
    def train_osr_model(self):
        """ Train the optical speech recognizer
        """
        print "\nTraining OSR"
        validation_ratio = 0.3
        batch_size = 32
        with h5py.File(self.training_save_fn, "r") as training_save_file:
            sample_count = int(training_save_file.attrs["sample_count"])
            sample_idxs = range(0, sample_count)
            sample_idxs = np.random.permutation(sample_idxs)
            training_sample_idxs = sample_idxs[0:int((1-validation_ratio)*sample_count)]
            validation_sample_idxs = sample_idxs[int((1-validation_ratio)*sample_count):]
            training_sequence_generator = self.generate_training_sequences(batch_size=batch_size, 
                                                                           training_save_file=training_save_file,
                                                                           training_sample_idxs=training_sample_idxs)
            validation_sequence_generator = self.generate_validation_sequences(batch_size=batch_size, 
                                                                               training_save_file=training_save_file,
                                                                               validation_sample_idxs=validation_sample_idxs)

            print "Sample Idxs: {0}\n".format(sample_idxs) # FOR DEBUG ONLY
            print "Training Idxs: {0}\n".format(training_sample_idxs) # FOR DEBUG ONLY
            print "Validation Idxs: {0}\n".format(validation_sample_idxs) # FOR DEBUG ONLY

            pbi = ProgressDisplay()
            self.osr.fit_generator(generator=training_sequence_generator,
                                   validation_data=validation_sequence_generator,
                                   samples_per_epoch=len(training_sample_idxs),
                                   nb_val_samples=len(validation_sample_idxs),
                                   nb_epoch=10,
                                   max_q_size=1,
                                   verbose=2,
                                   callbacks=[pbi],
                                   class_weight=None,
                                   nb_worker=1)

    def generate_training_sequences(self, batch_size, training_save_file, training_sample_idxs):
        """ Generates training sequences from HDF5 file on demand
        """
        while True:
            # generate sequences for training
            training_sample_count = len(training_sample_idxs)
            batches = int(training_sample_count/batch_size)
            remainder_samples = training_sample_count%batch_size
            if remainder_samples:
                batches = batches + 1
            # generate batches of samples
            for idx in xrange(0, batches):
                if idx == batches - 1:
                    batch_idxs = training_sample_idxs[idx*batch_size:]
                else:
                    batch_idxs = training_sample_idxs[idx*batch_size:idx*batch_size+batch_size]

                print batch_idxs # FOR DEBUG ONLY

                X = training_save_file["X"][batch_idxs]
                Y = training_save_file["Y"][batch_idxs]



                yield (np.array(X), np.array(Y))

    def generate_validation_sequences(self, batch_size, training_save_file, validation_sample_idxs):
        while True:
            # generate sequences for validation
            validation_sample_count = len(validation_sample_idxs)
            batches = int(validation_sample_count/batch_size)
            remainder_samples = validation_sample_count%batch_size
            if remainder_samples:
                batches = batches + 1
            # generate batches of samples
            for idx in xrange(0, batches):
                if idx == batches - 1:
                    batch_idxs = validation_sample_idxs[idx*batch_size:]
                else:
                    batch_idxs = validation_sample_idxs[idx*batch_size:idx*batch_size+batch_size]

                print batch_idxs # FOR DEBUG ONLY

                X = training_save_file["X"][batch_idxs]
                Y = training_save_file["Y"][batch_idxs]

                yield (np.array(X), np.array(Y))
```

Here are the functions that preprocesses and saves the training data into an HDF5 file:

```
def process_training_data(self):
    """ Preprocesses training data and saves them into an HDF5 file
    """
    # load training metadata from config file
    training_metadata = {}
    training_classes = []
    with open(self.config_file) as training_config:
        training_metadata = json.load(training_config)
        training_classes = sorted(list(training_metadata.keys()))

        print "".join(["\n",
                       "Found {0} training classes!\n".format(len(training_classes)),
                       "-"*40])
        for class_label, training_class in enumerate(training_classes):
            print "{0:<4d} {1:<10s} {2:<30s}".format(class_label, training_class, training_metadata[training_class])
        print ""

    # count number of samples
    sample_count = 0
    sample_count_by_class = [0]*len(training_classes)
    for class_label, training_class in enumerate(training_classes):
        # get training class sequeunce paths
        training_class_data_path = training_metadata[training_class]
        training_class_sequence_paths = [os.path.join(training_class_data_path, file_name)
                                         for file_name in os.listdir(training_class_data_path)
                                         if (os.path.isfile(os.path.join(training_class_data_path, file_name))
                                             and ".mov" in file_name)]
        # update sample count
        sample_count += len(training_class_sequence_paths)
        sample_count_by_class[class_label] = len(training_class_sequence_paths)

    print "".join(["\n",
                   "Found {0} training samples!\n".format(sample_count),
                   "-"*40])
    for class_label, training_class in enumerate(training_classes):
        print "{0:<4d} {1:<10s} {2:<6d}".format(class_label, training_class, sample_count_by_class[class_label])
    print ""

    # initialize HDF5 save file, but clear older duplicate first if it exists
    try:
        print "Saved file \"{0}\" already exists! Overwriting previous saved file.\n".format(self.training_save_fn)
        os.remove(self.training_save_fn)
    except OSError:
        pass

    # process and save training data into HDF5 file
    print "Generating {0} samples from {1} samples via data augmentation\n".format(sample_count*self.samples_generated_per_sample,
                                                                                   sample_count)
    sample_count = sample_count*self.samples_generated_per_sample
    with h5py.File(self.training_save_fn, "w") as training_save_file:
        training_save_file.attrs["training_classes"] = np.string_(",".join(training_classes))
        training_save_file.attrs["sample_count"] = sample_count
        x_training_dataset = training_save_file.create_dataset("X", 
                                                               shape=(sample_count, self.frames_per_sequence, 3, self.rows, self.columns),
                                                               dtype="f")
        y_training_dataset = training_save_file.create_dataset("Y",
                                                               shape=(sample_count, len(training_classes)),
                                                               dtype="i")

        # iterate through each class data
        sample_idx = 0
        for class_label, training_class in enumerate(training_classes):
            # get training class sequeunce paths
            training_class_data_path = training_metadata[training_class]
            training_class_sequence_paths = [os.path.join(training_class_data_path, file_name)
                                             for file_name in os.listdir(training_class_data_path)
                                             if (os.path.isfile(os.path.join(training_class_data_path, file_name))
                                                 and ".mov" in file_name)]
            # iterate through each sequence
            for idx, training_class_sequence_path in enumerate(training_class_sequence_paths):
                sys.stdout.write("Processing training data for class \"{0}\": {1}/{2} sequences\r"
                                 .format(training_class, idx+1, len(training_class_sequence_paths)))
                sys.stdout.flush()

                # accumulate samples and labels
                samples_batch = self.process_frames(training_class_sequence_path)
                label = [0]*len(training_classes)
                label[class_label] = 1
                label = np.array(label).astype("int32")

                for sample in samples_batch:
                    x_training_dataset[sample_idx] = sample
                    y_training_dataset[sample_idx] = label

                    # update sample index
                    sample_idx += 1

            print "\n"

        training_save_file.close()

        print "Training data processed and saved to {0}".format(self.training_save_fn)

def process_frames(self, video_file_path):
    """ Preprocesses sequence frames
    """
    # haar cascades for localizing oral region
    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
    mouth_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_mcs_mouth.xml')

    video = cv2.VideoCapture(video_file_path)
    success, frame = video.read()

    frames = []
    success = True

    # convert to grayscale, localize oral region, equalize frame dimensions, and accumulate valid frames 
    while success:
      success, frame = video.read()
      if success:
        # convert to grayscale
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # localize single facial region
        faces_coords = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame, 1.3, 5)
        if len(faces_coords) == 1:
          face_x, face_y, face_w, face_h = faces_coords[0]
          frame = frame[face_y:face_y + face_h, face_x:face_x + face_w]

          # localize oral region
          mouth_coords = mouth_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame, 1.3, 5)
          threshold = 0
          for (mouth_x, mouth_y, mouth_w, mouth_h) in mouth_coords:
            if (mouth_y > threshold):
                threshold = mouth_y
                valid_mouth_coords = (mouth_x, mouth_y, mouth_w, mouth_h)
            else:
                pass
          mouth_x, mouth_y, mouth_w, mouth_h = valid_mouth_coords
          frame = frame[mouth_y:mouth_y + mouth_h, mouth_x:mouth_x + mouth_w]

          # equalize frame dimensions
          frame = cv2.resize(frame, (self.columns, self.rows)).astype('float32')

          # accumulate frames
          frames.append(frame)

        # ignore multiple facial region detections
        else:
            pass

    # equalize sequence lengths 
    if len(frames) < self.frames_per_sequence:
        frames = [frames[0]]*(self.frames_per_sequence - len(frames)) + frames
    frames = np.array(frames[-self.frames_per_sequence:])

    # function to normalize and add channel dimension to each frame
    proc_frame = lambda frame: np.array([frame / 255.0]*3)

    samples_batch = [np.array(map(proc_frame, frames))]
    # random transformations for data augmentation
    for _ in xrange(0, self.samples_generated_per_sample-1):
        rotated_frames = random_rotation(frames, rg=4.5)
        shifted_frames = random_shift(rotated_frames, wrg=0.05, hrg=0.05)
        sheared_frames = random_shear(shifted_frames, intensity=0.08)
        zoomed_frames = random_zoom(sheared_frames, zoom_range=(1.05, 1.05))
        samples_batch.append(np.array(map(proc_frame, zoomed_frames)))

    return samples_batch
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error comes from two things :

- The one you are reading comes from the fact that `batch_idxs` is an array, not a list. h5py objects accept indexing with lists. But even if you change

  ```
  X = training_save_file["X"][list(batch_idxs)]
  ```

  you will still get an error. This comes from some restrictions about the list indexing. That brings us to the second point.
- If you read the [doc you sent me](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#fancy-indexing), this is written :

  > The following restrictions exist:
  >
  > - List selections may not be empty
  > - Selection coordinates must be given in increasing order
  > - Duplicate selections are ignored
  > - Very long lists (> 1000 elements) may produce poor performance

  The second bullet is our issue : your random shuffling when creating `training_sample_idxs` makes the index order random and the dataset is expecting them in ecreasing order. This is a limitation you will have to deal with, but it is not too constraining as the order in a batch doesn't matter, the model will be optimized on the whole batch anyway.

Does that help?

Comment: Hello Nassim thank you for your response. "X" and "Y" are datasets, not groups, and I believe that the right way to access dataset "X", for example, is `X = training_save_file["X"][batch_idxs]`, as the documentation indicates: http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#fancy-indexing

Comment: I still believe the error comes from this line. To help us troubleshout, can you post how you create the HDF5 file initially?

Comment: Hello Nassim I have updated the question with the functions that preprocess and save the training data into an HDF5 file.

Comment: did you try to print some data before fitting? just to see if everything is fine in the data_processing :)

Comment: Thank you! This is indeed the solution :)